# How to set symbolic name for a directory in terminal directory indentifier?

Tags: command-line

First what do I mean by "terminal directory identifier"? The following picture will explain:

[image]

So it is the highlighted text on the picture.

So I would like that, when ever I find myself in say that particular directory, I would like to see some other text instead of "/media/mladen/Seagate Data/Data". 
That is the directory I use quite often so it would make sense to set a shorter name for it.

Comment: So , essentially you asked how to make the current working directory that shows up in prompt shorter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you are in your home directory:

```
cd ~
```

Then (using your example):

```
ln -s "/media/mladen/Seagate Data" data
```

This will create a symbolic link named `data` in your home directory. Your can enter it using `cd data` and that is the name that will show in your *shell prompt* (the proper name for what you call "terminal directory identifier").

If you are in another directory, you can also do `cd ~/data` to go into your data directory.

Answer (score 1):

What Adrien's answer provides is merely creating a symlink for one specific directory. This will get annoying really fast when you want to do that same process for 125 directories over and over.

What's far more simple is to use edit your prompt. For instance, here's what I use:

```
bash-4.3$ PS1='$([ "$PWD" == "/" ] && echo / || echo ${PWD##*/}) $ '
/ $ cd /home
home $
```

This basically sets prompt to show last word of the full path of current working directory if it's anything else than root directory `/`. To make such change permanent, place

```
 PS1='$([ "$PWD" == "/" ] && echo / || echo ${PWD##*/}) $ '
```

at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file, save, run `source ~/.bashrc` and you're done. This works for all directories that you visit, and will not require making symlinks each and every time

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand this since I'm still a beginner. But based on what you've said, I believe it is a better solution.

Comment: @Scarass  Basic idea is that the  `user@machine directory: $` part can be controlled via `PS1` variable, and you can either change that at will or make change permanent in `~/.bashrc` file. Don't worry, it'll make sense with time as you continue the journey into Linux :)